# Why the 3d sound of my object stays the same in bge?

Tags: game-engine

I created a river and decided to put a sound to that river,but the sound stays the same,no matter how far or how near I am going to the river.I used 3d sound option in game logic in blender game and I did the properties as I saw in a clip on YouTube,but nothing has changed.How can I fix that problem?[image]

Comment: I have put .wav file,but with no result.Also when I increase maximum gain,the sound disappears.

Comment: In the picture i saw that the [maximun distance](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_SoundActuator.html?highlight=distance_maximum#bge.types.KX_SoundActuator.distance_maximum) is set to infinite, which means that Wherever you stand the volumen would be the same.

Comment: And what values must I have in 3d sound in my situation to run the sound properly?

Comment: How far away you want no sound?, put some value and test it.

Comment: I tested it many times with different values ,but as I said the sound stays the same.I want to have no sound from where is my camera as you see in the picture.

Comment: Take a look to my answer and change play stop to play end in the actuator i just forgot

Comment: How can I send my .blend file?

Comment: [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), copy and paste de link of your question then upload the file and finally [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/97666/edit) the question and paste the link provided when you upload.

Comment: Shit.My file is too big to send.I used your values in your answer,but my sound decreased and it stays decreased no matter where I go ,thats the only thing that has changed.I used exactly what you posted.Is it possible the problem is a bug,or I wasn't enabled something?

Comment: Have you downloaded the file i post in my answer to compare with your file?. There is nothing else to enable, but if you are using 50 as maximun distance try to increase to 100, 200,500, clearly the problem is not the sound actuator, the problem is your objects scale. And i dont think is a bug since its working as expected for me. Try to minimize the size of your blend making a copy and deleting everything that is not related to the problem, just leave the object that produce the sound and the camera and try to upload again.

Comment: I can't delete the rest,because I will go on a olympiad with my friends to present this project.The main character will search for artefacts in this game and I want the sound to work properly,because the jury will criticize us about the sound.We can make the other objects, but the adjusting of the sound is our problem.

Comment: Well then there is nothing more i can do.

Comment: What is this option "roll off" in 3d sound?Is there anything I can change there?

Comment: I did what you advised.I opened new .blend file,I clicked "append" and have imported the water and the sound,then I tested and the same thing happens.When I get close my camera,the sound is decreased and when the camera is far away ,it still stays decreased.I am really desperate.

Comment: The idea of the new .blend file, is that you can upload it and post the link so i can download it and check what is going on, and then give a solution to you.

Comment: I sent my .blend file.It is in my answer.What's my problem exactly and how to fix it?

Comment: @Strapicarus  Have you looked to my .blend file that I sent you in my answer?Did you find a solution to my sound?

Answer (score 1):

In the `sound actuator` set: `minimun gain to 0.0`, `maximun gain to 1.0` and `maximun distance to ~50 (estimate from the image provided)`, i dont know the scales you are using but the camera appear to be at ~50 units from the sound position. The scales of your blend are weird so is dificult to say something near reallity.

Here is a .blend to demonstrate, just press <kbd>P</kbd> and then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to move the camera. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my .blend file for 3d sound.Hopefully you will find solution to this problem.
[image]